# How to remove gradient border in "Linear Layout"?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

So I made a linear layout(horizontal) as an object in my vertical layout, to put a button and a checkbox, they both go in, but there is a gradient border to the layout, and I can't figure out how to remove it.

I've tried modifying all the settings on the default IntelliJ "attributes" for the layout.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:visibility="visible">
            <CheckBox
                    android:text="@string/remember_me"
                    android:layout_width="168dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/rememberBox"
            />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/user_register_button"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="33dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/action_register_short" android:background="#fc4141"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
```

[Full Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn58D.png)

Comment: What dose intellij idea have to do with styling?can you show the layout?

Comment: Added a picture of it!

Comment: ok, this is in context of the overall layout, so also give the complete layout not just the piece as context may affect

Comment: It's only visible in the layout mode of android studio and whenever application will be up and running it will be gone.

Comment: yes click outside of the linear layout and hopefully you will see no shadow-border  , you can also check in preview mode

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the background of your horizontal Linear Layout as

android:background="#ffffff"

Comment: I tried that, but it only affects the background of the layout void of the border sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution was really dumb, I ran it and the edge was still there. I changed the background to "#ffffff" and it was still present, after changing it back it went away.